# Writing Euclid's proposition "Ratios which are the same with the same ratio are also the same with one another" in contemporary style

Tags: relations

I need to write the Proposition 11 in Book 5 of Euclid's *Elements* according to contemporary style. It states that:

> Ratios which are the same with the same ratio are also the same with
>   one another.

The clue in book says that it is about transitivity. However I could not indicate it mathematically.

May you help me to write it by using an if-then statement or another way? Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about if $a/b=c/d$ and $e/f=c/d$ then $a/b=e/f$?

Comment: thank you very much Mr. Tanner

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let a, b and c be rational. If $a=b$ and $b=c,$ then $a=c.$

Comment: Euclid's "ratios" are not the same as rational numbers.  (They are essentially equivalent to positive real numbers.)

Comment: @EricWofsey, We should supposedly take your word for it, huh?